# Select values from SQLiteDatabase. Code 1 error?

Tags: android

Im creating an app to store entries. I am trying to select the relevant information from the database and display. The information is brought to the screen after clicking on a task and that task with the information is shown.

This is my entry screen class where the values are shown.

```
    getDAO = new DAO(this);
    Cursor showDiaryEntries = getDAO.queryDiary(Diary.DiaryItem.FULL_PROJECTION, Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE+" = "+fieldTitle, null);

    Long fieldDate = showDiaryEntries.getLong(1);
    Long fieldTime = showDiaryEntries.getLong(2);
    String fieldEntry = showDiaryEntries.getString(3);

    mDate.setText(String.valueOf(fieldDate));
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Date "+ fieldDate);
    mTime.setText(String.valueOf(fieldTime));
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Time "+ fieldTime);
    mEntry.setText(fieldEntry);
    Log.i(TAG,"Field Entry "+ fieldEntry);
```

**Logcat:**

```
03-07 07:00:22.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-07 07:00:22.186: E/AndroidRuntime(1411):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.democo.mydiary/com.democo.mydiary.DiaryEntryActivity}:
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "there": syntax error
 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT diaryTitle, diaryDate, diaryTime,
 diaryEntry, diaryLat, diaryLong FROM diary WHERE (diaryTitle = Hi
 there) ORDER BY diaryDate DESC
```

Thanks

Comment: use `"column=?"` and parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Cursor showDiaryEntries = getDAO.queryDiary(Diary.DiaryItem.FULL_PROJECTION, Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE+" = "+fieldTitle, null);
```

to

```
Cursor showDiaryEntries = getDAO.queryDiary(Diary.DiaryItem.FULL_PROJECTION, Diary.DiaryItem.COLUMN_NAME_DIARY_TITLE+" = '"+fieldTitle+"'", null);
```

You missed the `' '`

WHERE (diaryTitle = **Hi there**)

**EDIT:**

Anyway, you code is very dangerous if the title of the diary contains chars like ', you could use the syntax x=? and edit your code to something like this:

```
cursor = db.query(true,
        "table_name",
        "what should return",
        "diaryName=?", /* here.. it's the WHERE arg anyway */
        new String[] { fieldTitle },    /** what should be added */
        null, null, null, null);
```

You use a different way to query so i used the normal query.

You can use prepared statements too. Using [`compileStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) and use [`SQLiteStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html)

Example:

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("SELECT diaryTitle, diaryDate, diaryTime,\n" +
        " diaryEntry, diaryLat, diaryLong FROM diary WHERE (diaryTitle " +
        "= ?) ORDER BY diaryDate DESC");
stmt.bindString(1, fieldTitle);
stmt.execute();
```

Anyway, with prepared statements you don't have a `Cursor`.

Comment: @Selvin yup, but if he do it in this way there should be a reason. I just fixed the code, i will add this anyway.

Comment: This has worked thank you!, but now I have a cursor out of bounds exception, although I already have information within the database. Any ideas?

Comment: Edited the question with prepared statements and the col=?.. anyway open a new question for the new problem

Answer (score 2):

In your Select query:

```
"...WHERE (diaryTitle = Hi there) ORDER BY..."
```

add the value for `diaryTitle`(as it is a String) in quotes

Comment: I don't want it to be hard coded in? It gets the information from the relevant item which was clicked, therefore if I put "hi there" it would only ever get entries with the name hi there.... If only I could do that :p

Comment: @barryspikebob sorry about that, my bad. Saw the error and jumped to the answer, will edit

Answer (score 1):

Literal fields must be single-quoted:
i.e.:

```
"... WHERE (diaryTitle = '"  + searchField +"') ORDER BY ..."
```

Same when you INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE.